# Why can't I modify my current user entity in symfony?

Tags: symfony

I stumbled over some strange behaviour in symfony 2.6 concerning the current user. I'm using Doctrine and a mysql database. Now consider this example:

```
class StartController extends Controller {
   public function welcomeAction() {
     if ($this->getUser()) {
       $this->getUser()->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
       $this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->flush();
       ... some more code ...
```

No update statement has been executed. So I modified my controller like this:

```
class StartController extends Controller {
   public function welcomeAction() {
     if ($this->getUser()) {
       $managedUserEntity = $this->get('doctrine')
           ->getRepository('MyBundle:User')
           ->find($this->getUser()->getUuid());
       $managedUserEntity->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
       $this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->flush();
       ... some more code ...
```

Nothing. I can load, modify and update every other entity, but not the user. I'm quite sure, this worked at least in symfony 2.5, but obviously not any more. Or maybe I made some bad configuration settings.

Comment: are this user has been logged in?

Comment: Yes, it's the current logged-in user.

Comment: try `var_dump($this->getUser())` or/and `var_dump($this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('MyBundle:User')->find($this->getUser()->getId()))`

Comment: How would this help me to modify the entity in the database?

Comment: can You print Your User Model?

Comment: @Hennes Are you sure `$this->getUser()` is not returning `null` value?

Comment: @xurshid29: Definitely. The entity is nicely filled. Otherwise I would get an exception at $this->getUser()->setLastLogin(...

Comment: @ghanbari: My user entity just implements the Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface, because I use the entity for authentication.

Comment: @Hennes I don't think you'd get an exception if condition doesn't meet..

Comment: I debugged the lines: They were executed!

Comment: @Hennes Aren't you using any `preUpdate` listener/subscriber which calls `clear()` method?

Comment: No, I have implemented no event listeners so far. Just a User, a login page and a welcome page. I can't even find any errors or warnings in the logs. As if the lines were not been executed. But they were.

Comment: Shouldn't `->find($this->getUser()->getUuid());` be `->find($this->getUser()->getId());`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist your object:

```
$this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->persist($managedUserEntity);
$this->get('doctrine')->getManager()->flush();
```

Comment: No, the entity is already managed. But anyway: If I'd call persist, it would not change a bit in the behaviour. Tried it.